# pma_tracking not exist in engine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

So I forgot my xampp password then I reset it on config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

Then I made it into the phpmyadmin but everything come to an error

I can't select my table.

I can't select my database.

Even I can select the export button.

It keeps saying `#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine`

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a look at this [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask or answer questions and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.